# Angular 8 - Content of router-outlet and/or named router-outlet is not always displayed

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular8

Please help me fix the point 1, 4 and 5 here below.

**1) Rendering at application load (dossier-sidenav is not displayed):**

[image]

**2) Rendering if I type the correct url in navigation bar (works well):**

[image]

**3) Rendering when I click on the second menu after application load (works well):**

[image]

**4) Rendering when I click on the second menu and then on the first menu (the url is not correct and the primary outlet-router content is not displayed):**

[image]

**5) Rendering when I click on the second menu and then on the first menu and then again on the second menu(vacancies-sidenav is not displayed):**

[image]

**TestLibLayout/.../shell.component.html:**

```html
<fps-navbar [sidenav]="sidenav">
  <ng-container fps-navbar-items>
    <ng-content select="[fps-navbar-items]"></ng-content>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container fps-navbar-auth>
    <ng-content select="[fps-navbar-auth]"></ng-content>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container fps-navbar-language>
    <ng-content select="[fps-navbar-language]"></ng-content>
  </ng-container>
</fps-navbar>

<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav
    #sidenav
    class="sidenav"
    [fixedInViewport]="false"
    [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
    [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
    [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false"
  >
    <ng-container #content></ng-container>

    <router-outlet name="sidenav"></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav>

  <main>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <ng-component></ng-component>
  </main>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**TestProject/.../app.component.html:**

```html
<fps-shell>
  <ng-container fps-navbar-items>
    <a
      mat-button
      [routerLink]="['dossier', { outlets: { sidenav: ['dossier'] } }]"
      routerLinkActive="mat-accent"
    >
      {{ 'Employee.MyDossier.Title' | translate }}
    </a>
    <a
      mat-button
      [routerLink]="[
        { outlets: { primary: ['vacancies'], sidenav: ['vacancies'] } }
      ]"
      routerLinkActive="mat-accent"
    >
      {{ 'Vacancies.Title' | translate }}
    </a>
  </ng-container>
</fps-shell>
```

**TestProject/.../dossier-sidenav.component.html:**

```html
<mat-nav-list>
  <a
    mat-list-item
    [routerLink]="['personal-info']"
    routerLinkActive="router-link-active"
  >
    Personal info
  </a>
  <a
    mat-list-item
    [routerLink]="['career']"
    routerLinkActive="router-link-active"
  >
    Career
  </a>
  <a
    mat-list-item
    [routerLink]="['promotion']"
    routerLinkActive="router-link-active"
  >
    Promotion
  </a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

**TestProject/.../vacancies-sidenav.component.html:**

```html
<mat-nav-list>
  <a
    mat-list-item
    [routerLink]="['description']"
    routerLinkActive="router-link-active"
  >
    Description
  </a>
  <a
    mat-list-item
    [routerLink]="['vacancy']"
    routerLinkActive="router-link-active"
  >
    Vacancy
  </a>
  <a
    mat-list-item
    [routerLink]="['test']"
    routerLinkActive="router-link-active"
  >
    Test
  </a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

**TestProject/.../app.routes.ts:**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: 'dossier',
  loadChildren: () =>
  import('./my-dossier/my-dossier.module').then(m => m.MyDossierModule)
},
{
  path: 'vacancies',
  loadChildren: () =>
  import('./my-vacancies/my-vacancies.module').then(
    m => m.MyVacanciesModule
  )
},
{
  path: '404',
  component: NotFoundComponent
},
{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: 'dossier',
  pathMatch: 'full'
},
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '404' }
];
```

**TestProject/.../my-dossier.routes.ts:**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  component: MyDossierContainerComponent,
  children: [
  {
    path: 'personal-info',
    component: PersonalInfoContainerComponent,
    resolve: { info: PersonalInfoResolverService }
  },
  {
    path: 'career',
    component: CareerContainerComponent,
    resolve: { careerLines: CareerLinesResolverService }
  },
  {
    path: 'promotion',
    component: PromotionContainerComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'personal-info',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
]
},
{
  path: 'dossier',
  component: MyDossierSidenavComponent,
  outlet: 'sidenav'
}
];
```

**TestProject/.../my-vacancies.routes.ts:**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  component: VacancyListContainerComponent,
  resolve: { vacancies: VacancyListResolverService }
},
{
  path: 'vacancies',
  component: MyVacanciesSidenavComponent,
  outlet: 'sidenav'
},
{
  path: ':id',
  component: VacancyDetailContainerComponent,
  resolve: { vacancy: VacancyDetailResolverService }
}
];
```